# set element attribute with jquery within a loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a div element inside while (mysql query). So for every entry I want id to increment by 1. If I have "div id="0"" initially, with every new object I want id++. I have no idea how to do it and tried something like this:

```
<?php //some code
for ($i = 0; $i < $sent+1; $i++)  {
        ?><script>jQuery(".list-row").attr("id", "$i")</script> <?php //some code
```

.list row is a class of div element. Any ideas how to do it in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it for you

```
<?php //some code
for ($i = 0; $i < $sent+1; $i++)  {
    echo '<script>jQuery(".list-row").attr("id", "' . $i . '")</script>';
}
```

Or maybe this would be better and more readable later

```
<?php //some code
for ($i = 0; $i < $sent+1; $i++)  {
    echo '<script>jQuery(".list-row").attr("id", "sent_' . $i . '")</script>';
}
```